# Android FragmentTransaction setTransitionStyle

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to customize my `FragmentTransaction` transitions and I came across the `setTransitionStyle` method. It takes in an xml resource id for a style, but I have no idea what the xml resource would look like. I know you can define animation styles for activities, and I assume the xml needed for this method is similar, but I can't find any documentation on the required format (e.g. the xml attributes/nodes needed to make this work).

**EDIT1** (this is what I'm doing now in my FragmentActivity):

```
public void pushFolderFrag(Fragment folderFrag, String backStackID) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.SplitView_MasterContainer, folderFrag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(backStackID);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
    //transaction.setTransitionStyle(arg0);//what does the format for this resource look like??

    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: It takes an animation object, though it is not clear what (I didn't dig deep enough into the Android source). The following worked but did nothing: `transaction.setTransitionStyle(android.R.attr.fragmentFadeExitAnimation);`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on this link

https://github.com/kedzie/Support_v4_NineOldAndroids

> **Transition style resources**
>
> Specify transition animations in a style resource.
>
> Create a style resource `res/values/styles.xml'
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <resources>
>     <!-- Override standard Transitions with a Style -->
>     <style name="MyTransitionStyle">
>         <item name="fragmentFadeEnterAnimation">@animator/fade_enter</item>
>         <item name="fragmentFadeExitAnimation">@animator/fade_exit</item>
>         <item name="fragmentOpenEnterAnimation">@animator/flip_left_in</item>
>         <item name="fragmentOpenExitAnimation">@animator/flip_left_out</item>
>         <item name="fragmentCloseEnterAnimation">@animator/flip_right_in</item>
>         <item name="fragmentCloseExitAnimation">@animator/flip_right_out</item>
>     </style>
> </resources>
> ```
>
> Specify the resource and transition in the transaction
>
> ```
> tx.setTransitionStyle(R.style.MyTransitionStyle);
> tx.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not exactly answers the question, but why don't you use `setCustomAnimations()` instead?
This call takes [**property animation** resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Property) if you use Android 3+, and [**view animation** resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View) if you use the Support Package.